# Skipping CI build to run from bitbucket to jenkins

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, webhooks, skip

I have configured webhook in my bitbucket repository which is running a jenkins pipeline everytime a commit is made.
Now, i m using maven release plugin and everytime it makes commit to the repo while preparing a release, it triggers the pipeline. I do not want this pipeline to get triggered as there is no code change in the repo except the version change in the pom.xml file for the next development iteration. 
This is the endless loop and it never stops.

What i tried-

```
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M1</version> 
                        <configuration>
                            <checkModificationExcludes>
                            <checkModificationExclude>GIT_LOG</checkModificationExclude>
                            </checkModificationExcludes>  
                            <scmCommentPrefix>"[skip ci]"</scmCommentPrefix>
                        </configuration>      
                    </plugin>
```

i tried this thinking that if the commit message contains [skip ci], it will not trigger but its still not working.

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks

Abhishek Somani

Comment: CAn anyone please reply on this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?